# Python - Using isin on my dataframe throws an error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and one of the columns is a list. I am trying to use isin but I keep getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[5,4,3,6], [7,8,9,0]], 'B': [[1,2,3,5], [1,2,6,8]]})

  df[df['A'].isin([3, 6])]
```

The intended output should be:

```
      A           B
1  [5,4,3,6]  [1,2,3,5]
```

How would I go about solving this problem, I have tried to use apply but I can't figure it out?

Comment: What's your intended output?

Comment: df['A'] is a list and as such, isin will not work, as the error rightly explains. you need a single value(number, string,...). Have a look at the documentation for further explanation. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `set` instead of `list`... for **all** keys to exist in the list try using [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: {'3', '6'}.issubset(set(x)))]
# shorthand df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: {'3', '6'} < set(x))]
```

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['5','6','3','4'], ['1','2','1','3']], 'B': [[1,2,3,5],[6,7,8,9]]})

#              A             B
# 0  [5, 6, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 5]
# 1  [1, 2, 1, 3]  [6, 7, 8, 9]

df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: {'3', '6'}.issubset(set(x)))]
```

[out]

```
              A             B
0  [5, 6, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

---

If you only require **at least one** of the keys to exist, use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: bool({'3', '6'}.intersection(set(x))))]
# shorthand df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: bool({'3', '6'} & set(x)))]
```

[out]

```
              A             B
0  [5, 6, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 5]
1  [1, 2, 1, 3]  [6, 7, 8, 9]
```